# Django can't load app

Tags: django, django-apps

I'm using django 1.4, after i created the project using `django-admin`, I create an app, add it to `settings.py` in `INSTALLED_APPS` but then when I do `manage.py runserver` I get **Error: no module named myapp**
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please update your question with your directory layout, and your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: How did you create myapp ? By using ./manage.py ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have two things:

- correct path. You should be able to do ./manage.py shell and then import 'myapp' if not try 'myproject.myapp'
- models.py in your app folder and `__init__.py`